# Will a copper cooling loop affect a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, cooling

I would like to add external water cooling to an air-cooled brush-type permanent magnet DC motor. My first inclination is to coil soft copper fridge line around the motor a few times, attach a pump, radiator+fan, and a temperature relay to have it kick on automatically. Is the uninsulated copper water line likely to introduce any side effects, e.g. additional resistance, eddy currents, spontaneous nuclear fission, etc? Is there a better solution besides having the forethought to purchase a water-cooled motor in the first place?

Comment: Any well designed motor will have "iron" in it to direct the magnetic field so that the magnetic field is mostly confined within the motor, although a small amount of magnetic field will escape. Note that a great many motors have conductive casings, so the amount of leakage must not be so great that it induces high eddy currents in the casings, nor do the casings adversely affect the efficiency of the motor. If your copper pipe is outside the casing, I would suspect that the interaction with the magnetic field would not be so great as to be problematic.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy If you post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any well designed motor will have "iron" in it to direct the magnetic field so that the magnetic field is mostly confined within the motor, although a small amount of magnetic field will escape. Note that a great many motors have conductive casings, so the amount of leakage must not be so great that it induces high eddy currents in the casings, nor do the casings adversely affect the efficiency of the motor. If your copper pipe is outside the casing, I would suspect that the interaction with the magnetic field would not be so great as to be problematic.